# Yet another there is vs there are

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, there-is

The question about the correct use of there is vs there are pops up quite often.

However I couldn't find any reference to a case similar to the one below.
My wife is writing a crochet pattern with the following sentence:

Count the stitches all around - make sure **there is an odd number of stitches**.

Word's grammar correction tool suggests: make sure **there are an odd number of stitches**.

I myself find the "there are" version more pleasing to the ear. However I think my wife is correct in stating that the subject should be considered to be **odd number of stitches** and not just **stitches**.

Which is correct?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Should it be marked as duplicate though. You are right that both in a way refer to the same question but it may be misleading to readers. I am new on this list so I will mark it as duplicate if you suggest so.

Comment: It's essentially to do with whether 'a number of' takes a singular or plural verb-form, not 'there is / are'; this has been answered before. Other members will hopefully close-vote accordingly. Don't worry about missing the odd duplicate; there are a lot of questions on ELU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun "number" by itself is singular, e.g., The *number* on his jersey *is* 88. However, the phrase "a number of" calls for a plural verb, e.g., *A number of* protesters *were* arrested.

http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-number-singular-or-plural/

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was missing. I will mark the question as answered